# responsabilidade em controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho meu Model Banco

```
public class Banco {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

e meu model ContaBancaria

```
public class ContaBancaria 
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Nome {get;set;}
  public Banco Banco {get;set;}
}
```

Vejamos, para cada um deles eu terei meu controller

```
BancoController
ContaBancariaController
```

Então eu tenho uma View "NovaContaBancaria",ela faz parte e todas as suas ações de Inserir/Editar/Deletar são do meu ContaBancariaController. Mas nela eu tenho uma combo com listagem dos bancos

De quem é a responsabilidade de buscar e me mandar essas informações do banco para a essa minha view?

Do BancoController por ter responsabilidade unica e quando necessário chamar o método dele para retornar, ou no ContaBancariaController por esses dados serem dele, ele ter o papel de listar e mandar?

Não sei se ficou claro, é um exemplo que pode acontecer, mas também pode haver mais de uma dependencia por exemplo...

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esse tipo de questão eu costumo criar uma camada de acesso a dados (`Dal`) e criar nela as funcionalidades que acessem dados.

Seguindo esse modelo, teríamos sua classe`BancoDAO` (Data Access Object) disponibilizando os dados de banco referentes à informação desejada que se relacione ao model `Banco`, que podem sem problema ser consumidos pela view.

Se quiséssemos disponibilizar esses dados em uma `ViewBag`, poderíamos fazer assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Bancos = new BancoDAO().ListarBancos(); // Busca os dados dos bancos

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Certo, então nesse teu exemplo, você faz com que a listagem de bancos seja mandada do controller que tem dependencia, no caso a listagem é feita no ContaBancariaController

Comment: No meu caso eu retorno um JsonResult, por isso saber de quem é a responsabilidade de mandar os dados da View

Comment: @Rod a **chamada** do método é feita no `ContaBancariaController`. Mas a **responsabilidade** de gerar a estrutura de dados é da **BancoDAO**

Comment: @Rod faz mais sentido armazenar os dados em uma ViewBag do que criar um novo método para buscar os dados de outro controller. Lembre-se que você estaria criando um método no controller apenas para retornar uma listagem de bancos.

Comment: ViewBag não posso usar nesse caso, já que estou usando Select2, logo preciso de um método que retorne um json

Comment: @Rod nesse caso faz mais sentido ter uma camada para prover esse dado (eu usaria Web API). Não faz muito sentido colocar isso em um controller, **na minha opinião**. Penso que um controller deve apenas controlar o fluxo de navegação e direcionar pedidos e respostas - um garçom mesmo.